# How to determine distance between two points in Poincare?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I study Poincare model as hyperbolic model. But honestly, I don't understand with this topic. I try to find some examples but nothing. Here is my problem.

> 1. Find the equation of the hyperbolic line (euclid circle) through $P(1/3,0)$ and $Q(0,1/3)$.
> 2. Distance between $P$ and $Q$.

In my textbook, distance in Poincare is $\left\lvert\ln\dfrac{(PQ')(QP')}{(PP')(QQ')}\right\rvert$. But how to find $P'$ and $Q'$?

Comment: $P'$ and $Q'$ are the ideal points on $\overleftrightarrow{PQ}$. In the Poincaré Disk Model, the (unique) orthogonal circle through $P$ and $Q$ meets the boundary circle at $P'$ and $Q'$, so take the circle you find in $(1)$ and intersect it with $x^2+y^2=1$.

Comment: @Blue Thank you for edited my post. Now, I know where P' and Q' are. But I still don't understand how to take the equation of hyperbolic line or the circle?

Comment: One way to find the equation of the hyperbolic line (Euclidean circle in the model) is to first find, say, the inverse of point $P$ in the boundary circle. That point, call it $R$, is defined by the property $|OP||OR|= 1$. Then the Euclidean circle you need passes through $P$, $Q$, and $R$. (In this case $R$ is easy to locate. And in fact, it would be convenient to also find the inverse of $Q$; call that $S$. Then the target circle will pass through all four of these points, so that its center lies on the perpendicular bisectors of $PR$ and $QS$, which are easy to determine.)

Comment: @Blue Yeah, really thank you, I find the circle now, I construct it by geogebra. But then how to answer number 2? How can I find PQ' or QP'?

Comment: In the distance formula for the Poincaré disk, $\ln\frac{|PQ'||QP'|}{|PP'||QQ'|}$, the various $|XY|$ terms are simply the *Euclidean* distances between the points $X$ and $Y$ in the model. So, just use the standard Cartesian distance formula.

Comment: @Blue Thank you for helping me. Now I can solve these problems. I calculate the distance is $\approx 1.010190$. Hope this is the right answer. Big thanks to you :)

Comment: Post your work as an answer so that we can up-vote your success. :)

Answer (score 1):

First, I use geogebra to solve it.

1. Draw a circle $C$ with $x^2+y^2=1$. Suppose $R$ and $S$ are inverse points $P,Q$ of circle $C$. By using inversion formula $|OP||PR|=1$ so $R=(3,0)$ and $S=(0,3)$. Now, suppose circle $D$ through $P,Q,R$. If $\ell$ is perpendicular bisector of $P,Q$ then $\ell$ pass the centre of circle $D$ in $(1.67,1.67)$. So the equation of the circle $D$ is $(x-1.67)^2+(y-1.67)^2=4.56$.
2. Intersection of two circles are $P'=(0.94,-0.34)$ and $Q'=(-0.34,0.94)$. Calculate $|PQ'|, |QP'|, |PP'|, |QQ'|$ by using distance formula in euclidean. Then
   $PQ=\left\lvert\ln\dfrac{(PQ')(QP')}{(PP')(QQ')}\right\rvert=\left\lvert\ln\dfrac{(1.16)(1.16)}{(0.7)(0.7)}\right\rvert\approx 1.01019$.